# Почему выводится пустой виджет таблицы?

Tags: c++, qt

Беру делаю форму с QTableWidget заполняю ее в mainwindow.cpp, но она выводится пустой. Что я делаю не так?

```
void MainWindow::createTable()
{
     //ui->tableView виджет QTableWidget из формы
    int n=3;
    //QTableWidget      tbl(n, n);
    QTableWidgetItem* ptwi = 0;
    QStringList       lst;

    lst << "First" << "Second" << "Third";
     ui->tableView->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(lst);
     ui->tableView->setVerticalHeaderLabels(lst);

    for (int i  = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            ptwi = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1,%2").arg(i).arg(j));
            ptwi->setText("niam");
            ui->tableView->setItem(i, j, ptwi);
        }
    }
     ui->tableView->resize(370, 135);
   // tbl.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит выставить количество столбцов / строк перед заполнением:

```
ui->tableView->setRowCount(n);
ui->tableView->setColumnCount(n);
```

Comment: Спс вам, мог бы и сам догадаться. Плюсую.